# Translations into Mongolian and Icelandic

Tags: translation, mongolian

I wish to translate into Mongolian the sentence "I have no home", and into Icelandic the sentence "However, I have the road".

I tried Google Translate, but couldn't fully trust the results.

I can't find sub-stackexchange categories of "Mongolian" and "Icelandic" so I gathered it would be appropriate to post this thread here :)

Any help or pointer would be awesome! Thanks!

Comment: "I have no home" can be translated into Mongolian in a number of ways, still all of them include the words for 'I' and 'homeless'. 'I' is 'би'. 'Home/house' is 'гэр', or 'гэр орон' (house-dwelling), or 'орон гэр' (dwelling-house). The '-less' is also a suffix in Mongolian, it is '-гүй'. Also, the verb 'am', 'байна', can be added at the end, but in such simple sentences it is usually omitted. So "I have no home" in Mongolian is one of the three: Би гэргүй. Би гэр оронгүй. Би орон гэргүй. I'd choose "Би гэргүй".

Comment: @YellowSky In all three choices you put forth, there is the suffix "-гүй". But I forgot to mention in the original post that I was seeking a word-by-word translation, i.e. "I have no home" can be translated into German as "Ich('I' in German) habe('have') keine('no') Heimat('home'). Is it possible to obtain such a word-by-word Mongolian translation?

Comment: As far as I know, the typical Mongolian sentence construction that means "I have no X" is "I X-less", so you can look at it as a word-by-word translation. Still, there's another way to say that, "At me X absent", in this case "at me" is "надад" (locative case of би), and "absent" is "байхгүй" (literary "beingless"), so the whole sentence is "Надад гэр байхгүй", or you can change "гэр" for any of its other synonyms. You know, the sentence is very simple, and my translations is exactly how your sentence is expressed in Mongolian. Besides, I strongly doubt that Mongolian has the verb "to have".

Comment: @snaefells: linguistics.stackexchange.com does not do translation requests. But the English Wiktionary does! Here's the link for you: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Translation_requests

Comment: @YellowSky Thanks so much! If the Mongolian word for absent has the spin of meaning of "beingless", that is just "wow"! P.S. I really do believe there is a verb "to have", or how do they say "I have 200 cows"? :) <perhaps, "I am not 200 cowless> ^_*

Comment: @hippietrail Got it! Will go there next time! Thanks^_^

Comment: @snaefells Many languages don't have a word for "to have" (Arabic, Hebrew, Altaic languages incl. Turkic and Mongolian) or don't use it in sentences like "I have 200 cows"(Russian). The way they do without "to have" is they put it this way: "At me there's 200 cows". In Russian one can even omit "there's": "У меня [есть] 200 коров" (the same in Arabic, there's no verb "to be" in Arabic). Turkish puts it this way: "There're my 200 cows". If you can find the Mongolian word for "to have", maybe in some dictionary, please tell me, that will be a miracle, because Mongolian _really_ doesn't have it.

Answer (score 2):

Semantically loaded, the things you request translated. Ah well, such is life. Based on my non-native knowledge of Icelandic, I'd translate both as: "Ég hef ekki heimili **en er ég með veginn**" (with the part you need highlighted). As for Mongolian, wait for some other answer I guess.

Comment: Haha, "such is life"! Thanks for the poeticism :) However, could you tell me how to say in Icelandic "However, I have the road." as a separate sentence rather than a part/clause of a sentence? (I have no knowledge of Icelandic, but it seems in "Ég hef ekki heimili eða er ég með veginn" you fused "I have no home" and "However, I have the road".

Comment: O yeah, and if you could also cast some gleaming twilight upon the way to pronounce that translated sentence it would be awesome!

Comment: Of course! Well if you want a separate sentence kinda thing - sorry for missing it heh - you could instead use "Samt (sem áður) er ég með veginn" I think. As for the pronunciation of it: [sam̥t (sem a͡ʊðʏr) er jeɣ með veʝɪn:] in IPA. I don't know how else to show it :\

Comment: haha cool.. But what do the parenthesized part mean? They are omissible?